# Logger object for a single software component in the Log4j2 environment

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, thread-safety, log4j

As per `log4j2` user guide , it looks like only one `Logger` object gets created  for a class.

If i call the static method `LogManager.getLogger("SomeClass")` from anywhere in my code , it should give me back the reference to the same logger object.

Do multiple threads in the application that have the above line of code , end up using the same logger object ?

Comment: it is a static call so, on that basis I will say yes. All threads calling with same Class Name will provide same instance of logger. That is until and unless you setup a custom logger repository which returns a different logger(object). Custom logger repo will mean that you can manipulate how the logger objects get stored and returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LogManager.getLogger("SomeClass") is a static call so, on that basis I will say yes If you make call to get logger for same class it will return the same logger object.

Different threads will not make any difference till it is same container.

All threads calling with same Class Name will provide same instance of logger. That is until and unless you setup a custom logger repository which returns a different logger(object). Custom logger repo will mean that you can manipulate how the logger objects get stored and returned.

I tested this in theory. Created 2 separate classes. Created logger for both the classes. Leaving the class name passed to the call same for both.

Called up logger to print their hash which comes out to be same.